# Assigning static IP address

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012

I want to assign a static IP address to my Windows Server 2012 virtual machine. I use a broadband connection via router. I added an IP address in the router's DHCP static IP table and provided the IP address and MAC address of the virtual machine's adapter, but my VM is still not getting that IP.

Guide me.

Comment: I am using VMware for virtual machine. I have brigded and NAT adapters . I tried using custom adapter and assigning IP address to them but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

To configure IPv4 for static addressing:

1) Click Start, click Control Panel, click Network and Internet, click Network and Sharing Center and then click Change Adapter Settings.
2) Right-click the connection to which you want to add a static IP address and then click Properties.
3) Acknowledge the UAC dialog and then double-click **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP/IPv4)**.
4) Click Use the following IP address, and do one of the following:

=> For a local area connection, in IP address, Subnet mask, and Default gateway, type the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway addresses.
=> For all other connections, in IP address, type the IP address.

5) Click Use the following DNS server addresses.
6) In Preferred DNS server and Alternate DNS server, type the primary and secondary DNS server addresses.

Comment: do i have to do this in VM? which network adapter should i use?